# How to anonymously post to Yammer

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

This is for a crowd sourcing use case. We are hosting an event to invite suggestions / criticism for newly introduced processess.

We are expecting that many users will not post their comments (i guess it is replies in yammer terminology) if not allowed to so anonymously.

What are the various ways I can acheive this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Yammer does not support absolute anonymity. For your use case, you may create a service account called Anonymous, generate an access token with the Anonymous user and then pass the token for all API POST request.